# Why can't I use `libmime` in my code? (OSError: mime.so: undefined symbol: magic_load)

Tags: c, libmagic

I try to use libmagic in my c code.
I compile the following code like this (`gcc mime.c -shared -o mime.so`). Unfortunately it throws me this error when using it: `OSError: mime.so: undefined symbol: magic_load`

mime.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <magic.h>

void get(char* argv[]) {
    magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_CONTINUE|MAGIC_ERROR/*|MAGIC_DEBUG*/|MAGIC_MIME);
    magic_load(myt,NULL);
    char value = magic_file(myt, argv[1]);
    magic_close(myt);

    return value;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with `libmagic`, try something like:

```
-lmagic
```